# Codeigniter 4: creating modules

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to create modules in Codeigniter 4 to work with HMVC. I tried following this user guide https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/modules.html, but cannot get it working.

I created a 'modules' folder, alongside the app, public, etc. folders.

Added to `app/config/autoload.php`

```
'Modules' => ROOTPATH.'modules'
```

Inside the modules folder, I created a 'Proef' folder, containing a Controllers folder and 'Proef.php' file.

The file contains the following;

```php
    namespace App\Modules\Proef\Controllers;
    class Proef extends \CodeIgniter\Controller
    {
      public function index() {
        echo 'hello!';
      }
    }
```

In the `app/config.routes.php` file I added

```php
    $routes->group('proef', ['namespace' => 'Modules\Proef\Controllers'], function($routes)
    {
        $routes->get('/', 'Proef::index');
    });
```

Yet, the following error persists:
Controller or its method is not found: `\Modules\Proef\Controllers\Proef::index`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

If you put your modules folder "alongside" and not under your app folder, then your namespace is wrong.

So you would have something like

```
app/
Modules/   ==> can be modules or Modules but must be set in autoload with the same case
    Proef/
       Controllers/
           Proef.php
```

NOTE: modules can be Modules or modules but the corresponding entry in the autoload must match.

1. For modules
   'Modules'     => ROOTPATH . 'modules'
2. For Modules 
   'Modules'     => ROOTPATH . 'Modules'

> It appears (from my limited testing) that the other folder names must
>   be 1st letter Upper case. This is under Apache on Linux.

let's use Modules for the folder name so in **Autoload.php** we would have...

```
$psr4 = [
    'App'         => APPPATH,                // To ensure filters, etc still found,
    APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH,                // For custom namespace
    'Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config',
    'Modules'     => ROOTPATH . 'Modules'
];
```

So your Proef Controller - **Proef.php** ... Note the namespace being used.

```
<?php
namespace Modules\Proef\Controllers;
use App\Controllers\BaseController;

class Proef extends BaseController {
    public function index() {
        echo 'Hello - I am the <strong>'. __CLASS__ . '</strong> Class';
    }
}
```

To make this accessible via the URL you can set the routes (**Routes.php**) to... (simple version)

```
$routes->get('/proef', '\Modules\Proef\Controllers\Proef::index');
```

To make it callable within other Controllers... ( I have borrowed **Home.php** for this)

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

use \Modules\Proef\Controllers\Proef;

class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $mProef = new Proef();
        $mProef->index();

        return view('welcome_message');
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

In your URL - 
/proef will result in the just the message
/home will result in the class message and the welcome page.

So hopefully this will help you figure this out. its a lot of fun :)

**Aside:**

You can put your Modules Folder anywhere. I put mine under app/ for ole times sake, which removes the need to add the entry in Autoload.php as they fall under app/ which is already defined.

The namespace and use statement need to be changed appropriately as well.

Answer (score 1):

Edit 
namespace to Modules\Proef\Controllers in Proef class

Answer (score 0):

I have created a package to automate the creation of CodeIgniter Modules using the CLI.

You can download it free from GitHub;

https://github.com/solomon-ochepa/codeigniter-modules

Below are a few commands you can run at the moment.

#### Make / Create

Generates a new Module.

```
php spark module:make Example
```

#### Delete

Delete a module.

```
php spark module:delete Example
```

#### Route

Generates a new Route file.

```
php spark module:route Example
```

#### Controllers

Generates a new Controller file.

```
php spark module:controller ExampleController Example
```

#### Migrations

Generates a new migration file.

```
php spark module:migration CreateExamplesTable Example
```

#### Migrate

Migrate a Module migration files.

```
php spark module:migrate Example
```

#### Seeders

Generates a new Module seeder file.

```
php spark module:seeder Example Example

php spark module:seeder ExampleSeeder Example
```

#### Seed

Run a db:seed command in a Module.

```
php spark module:seed Example

php spark module:seed Example ExampleSeeder
```

#### Entities

Generates a new module Entity class.

```
php spark module:entity Example Example
```

#### Models

Generates a new module Model file.

```
php spark module:model ExampleModel Example
```

I hope this will help.